# Pheanstalk_Command_DeleteCommand->parseResponse('NOT_FOUND', NULL)

Tags: php, beanstalkd

I got this error when I try to delete job from pheanstalk using

`$this->pheanstalkObj->delete($job);`

```
 /pheanstalk/classes/Pheanstalk/Connection.php(121): Pheanstalk_Command_DeleteCommand->parseResponse('NOT_FOUND', NULL)
 /pheanstalk/classes/Pheanstalk.php(508): Pheanstalk_Connection->dispatchCommand(Object(Pheanstalk_Command_DeleteCommand))
 /pheanstalk/classes/Pheanstalk.php(67): Pheanstalk->_dispatch(Object(Pheanstalk_Command_DeleteCommand))
 /Altibbi/BeanstalkEngine.php(844): Pheanstalk->delete(Object(Pheanstalk_Job))
 /var/www/altibbi/2.6.3.5/application/controllers/CliController.php(959): Altibbi_BeanstalkEngine->workQueue('recentactivity')
 /var/www/altibbi/2.6.3.5/application/controllers/CliController.php(123): CliController->beanstalkWorker('recentactivity')
/Zend/Controller/Action.php(514): CliController->indexAction()
 /Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('indexAction')
 /Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
```

what is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: The job does not exist, is buried or reserved by a client. And you can get that info from the documentation https://github.com/mikelbring/Pheanstalk/blob/master/pheanstalk/doc/protocol-1.3.txt

Comment: Thank you , yes the job does not exist, you can post your answer to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The job does not exist, is buried or reserved by a client. You can get more info about the responses in the [protocol description](https://github.com/mikelbring/Pheanstalk/blob/master/pheanstalk/doc/protocol-1.3.txt)

Comment: how can i stop it from flooding the laravel log sir? any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

"NOT_FOUND" if the job does not exist or is not either reserved by the client, ready, or buried. This could happen if the job timed out before the client sent the delete command.

Comment: From: 
https://github.com/mikelbring/Pheanstalk/blob/master/pheanstalk/doc/protocol-1.3.txt